# Homestead box version 0.5.0

Tags: vagrant, homestead

After install homestead box i'm creating ssh key and create test app on code/test(create laravel project) and add to

```
- map: test.app
  to: /home/vagrant/Code/test/public
```

set `serve test.app /home/Vagrant/Code/test/public`

have error

```
dos2unix: converting file /vagrant/scripts/serve.sh to Unix format ...
Failed to restart php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service not found.
```

and previous starting homestead up

```
    ==> default: Failed to restart php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service not found.
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

how to fix it?

```
UPD
```

may be it is not solution but work for me

find script serve.sh and rewrite

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

to

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

and set `serve test.app /home/Vagrant/Code/test/public`

but `homestead up` starting with `Failed to restart php5-fpm.service: Unit php5-fpm.service not found.`
may be homestead need locale php5-fpm

Comment: you can check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/homestead-php5-fpm-error?page=1

Comment: @FrédéricHenri there is no written solution in the box with php version 7